# Processing org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope Response throws an error

Tags: android, android-ksoap2

I have written a SoapSerializationEnvelope to request an asmx Web service for the data in android.And I am capturing the response for the Soap request as follows

```
  SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope=getSoapSeraializationEnvolope(request);
/*Here I have written code for Creating Soap request and Sending Soap request which has no problem at all*/
         SoapPrimitive resultsString;
            //Processing the response
            try
            {
            resultsString = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
            return resultsString.toString();
            }
```

And the Function of getSoapSerializationEnvolope is as follows

```
//Creating an Envelope here...
    private SoapSerializationEnvelope getSoapSeraializationEnvolope(SoapObject request) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envolope=new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envolope.dotNet=true;
        envolope.implicitTypes=true;
        envolope.setAddAdornments(false);
        envolope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        MarshalDouble marshaldDouble = new MarshalDouble();
        marshaldDouble.register(envolope);
        return envolope;
    }
```

But the problem here is when the webService returns a string data(for example-"Message Sent") there is no problem with the response,but when my webservice return a blank string data(i.e when it returns  " ") it gives an exception saying

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject cannot be cast to org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive
```

I have also tried casting into SoapObject instead of Soap Primitive but here I get the error when it is reverse(i.e When the string returned from web service has some data in it ,it throws an error).

Why is it so??

Thanks in Advance!!